Convert images to paint-like styles
We are looking to convert such as this one to paint-like styles, similar to those listed here. Is there a tool to achieve this?

Upload it to DALL-E or a similar AI system capable of image-to-image generartion and style transfer. If you are looking for models that you can run locally, check the "Computer Vision" model category on huggingface.com, especially those labeled with the "Unconditional image generation" tag, download and install from there (needs familiarity with Huggingface concepts of operation)

I found Arbitrary Style Transfer in the Browser.
